# Self structure and pointers in linklist

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

I have few confusion in understanding the linked list. Here is my full code.

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
}; node *head;



main()
{
head =new node;
head -> data=5;
head -> next=NULL;

node *ptr=new node;
ptr -> data=6;
head -> next=ptr;
ptr -> next= NULL;

}
```

1) The self defined struct node pointer in the structure is made to hold the address of structure of same type, according to this [link](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-pointer-structure-within-same-structure/) and what will be the size of `node *next`?

2) when we make 2nd node `ptr`, in the linked list we assign the address of 2nd node to the address part of 1st node, so we can assign the `&` sign how can we do that with  `head -> next=ptr;`

I am sorry for ask too basic things but I think I mixed concepts of pointers. Please help me to understand that

Comment: 1) the size of a pointer to struct `sizeof(node*)` is independent of the size of the struct `sizeof(node)`. 2) I don't even understand your confusion, please work your way through a [tutorial on pointers](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson6.html) to learn about the dereferencing `operator&`

Comment: @BeyelerStudios 
1) `sizeof(node*)` is showing me 8, the size of pointer, so it will not add the size of int?
2) I have understand the dereferencing `&` we use to get address of the variable to pointer. but here we have a pointer `ptr` so we have give the address of structure to the `head->next`

Comment: 1) `sizeof(node*)` has nothing to do with `int` or `sizeof(int)`, since `node` contains an `int`, `sizeof(node)` will depend on `sizeof(int)`. 2) I still don't understand your confusion: your question makes no sense, please read the tutorial I linked above for a complete answer

Comment: 2) so I want to know that when we have to give the address of pointer to the `head->next` we can directly did this `head->next=ptr`. I have confusion that when we do `int a=8` `int *p1,*p2;` `p1=&a;` `p2=p1 `
in that the address in `p1` of variable `a` is copied to `p2` so it will be same with `head->next=ptr`?

Comment: your question is addressed clearly in the tutorial...

Comment: you mean this part "As I mentioned, there are two ways to use the pointer to access information: it is possible to have it give the actual address to another variable. To do so, simply use the name of the pointer without the *. "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102898/discussion-between-dee-khan-and-beyelerstudios).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next is a pointer, so it has the size of a pointer, which means 8B in a 64-bit architecture. Of course, you can see this with a simple `sizeof(struct node *)`.

Comment: it is showing 8 byte, so any type of pointer will be of size 8 byte?

Comment: also can you tell me about the 2nd part of the question

Comment: A pointer is just a "special" `unsigned long int`. It contains an address, so, yes, it has always the same size (which depends on the system architecture).

I didn't understand exactly what's your problem in the second part, sorry.

Comment: so I want to know that when we have to give the address of pointer to the `head->next` we can directly did this `head->next=ptr`. I have confusion that when we do `int a=8` `int *p1,*p2;` `p1=&a;` `p2=p1`  in that the address in `p1` of variable `a` is copied to `p2` so it will be same with `head->next=ptr`?

Comment: Yes, you can do `head->next = ptr`, because are two pointers to `node`.
In the other case, you have to assign the address of `a` to `p1`, so you must write `p1=&a` (remember: `&a` means "address of a").
Is everything clear?

Comment: yes I understand that in 2nd case in which I assign the address of `a` to `p1` pointer so I must write `p1=&a` but I am asking the difference between `p2=p1` and `head->next = ptr`. In `p2=p1` the address of `a` which was assigned to `p1` is copied to `p2` but what will happen with `head->next = ptr`?

Comment: `ptr` is copied into `head->next`. So, `next`  contains the same value of `ptr`.

Comment: `ptr` is copied to `head->next`, does it means the address of ptr is copied to `head->next`?

Comment: No. The  content of ptr, which is an address, of course.

Comment: but in the first case the when we did `p2=p1` then pointer `p1` holding the address of `a` is copied to `p2` in this case `ptr` is a node type pointer and it has two sections data and self referential pointer so how it will copy its address to `head->next` that makes me confuse

Comment: in the above mention tutorial I have this statement "As I mentioned, there are two ways to use the pointer to access information: it is possible to have it give the actual address to another variable. To do so, simply use the name of the pointer without the *. "

Comment: Imagine you have:
`int a, b;
    int *p, *pt;
    p = &a;
`
Now, if you want to assign the value stored in `a` to `b`, you have to write `b=*p`, which means:"Take the address stored in p, go to that address, take the value stored there, and copy it into b".
IF you want to copy the ADDRESS of `a` in `pt`, you have to write `pt = p`, which means:"Take the value stored in p (which is the address of `a`), and copy it into pt. Is that clear?

Comment: Now, if you want to change the value stored in `a`, using pt, you have to write: `*pt = 4` (substitute 4 with whatever you want), which means:"Go to the address stored in pt, and put 4 there.

Comment: yes I understand this example. but `head->next =ptr` will give the address to head->next?

Comment: `head->next = ptr` is the same thing of `p2=p1` in your example. Exactly the same.
When you work with pointers, you don't have to care too much if you're talking about `int` or complex structures. You use the pointer always in the same way.

Comment: if it is same as you said then `p1` contains the address of `a` we know that because we assigned that. but in case of `ptr` it has the data section which is integer and node pointer then how it will give its own address to `head->next`

Comment: You defined ptr as a POINTER TO NODE, which means that ptr contains an address, as I said. ptr doesn't contain the struct.

Comment: as you said "You defined ptr as a POINTER TO NODE, which means that ptr contains an address" this is because self referential structure?

Comment: No, this is because a pointer will always contain an address; and this does not depend on the structure.
So, `ptr` is a pointer to `node`, and `next` too, so you can just assign ptr to next (`head->next = ptr`) without a cast.

Comment: You mean that pointer always contains its address itself so when have to assign its address to any other pointer then we simple do `head->next=ptr;`

Comment: Pointer contains always an address, and it has its own too, of course (`&ptr` gives you the address of `ptr`). So, with that instruction, `head->next` and `ptr` will contain the same value, which is the address of a `node` structure.

Comment: Ok I have tried this `int *p1,*p2;`, `p2=p1;` `cout<<p2<<"\t"<<&p1;` I have tried this according to what you  have said the output should be same but its not

Comment: The output is the same if you write `cout<<p2<<"\t"<<p1`.
You printed the address of p1, and the content of p2, which is an address.

Comment: in this case `cout<<p2<<"\t"<<p1`.  you printed the contents of both `p1` and `p2` which is same, right? but these content are address ?

Comment: Yes, the contents are addresses, because, ad I said, a pointer is a  variable which contains an address.